# How to command run for symfony2 in windows 7

Tags: windows, linux, command-line, symfony, ubuntu-11.10

I am working on Ubuntu environment **(LAMP)**.But when i install **symfony2** on **windows 7 starter** operating system i face problem when i try to make **entity** with command prompt in windows it not take **php app/console**

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: What did you try? What was the problem? What was the error? Etc. -- We are not clairvoyants.

Comment: I try to make entity on symfony2 framework with command prompt.The problem is basically for not run symfony2 command on windows.error not take php variable in windows command! Thanks for reapply.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add the PHP executable to your [PATH](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.installation.php#faq.installation.addtopath), or calling it with an absolute link: `c:\path\to\php\php.exe app/console`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I managed to add the environment variable with the absolute path. It works!

Answer (score 0):

Just go to the symfony folder and start writing the symfony commands ...

c:\path-to-symfony-project>
for example
"*c:\xampp\htdocs\test>*"