# where to run symfony2 debug commands?

Tags: symfony, command-line

Currently I am new to symfony2, I was just going through the basics and while reading the "The book" from symfony I came across some commands which can be used to debug the application like following commands

$ php app/console router:match /blog/my-latest-post

$ php app/console router:debug

So my question is:

1) From where to run these commands, from commandline?

2) How do you run them, is there something we need to install or some dependency?

Currently I am using WAMP server on windows 7 machine, just a localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. From command line, from your project. Check [**How to command run for symfony2 in windows 7**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11126325/how-to-command-run-for-symfony2-in-windows-7)
2. We use composer for update dependency. Chechk [**How to install Symfony2 Bundles with Composer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15225896/how-to-install-symfony2-bundles-with-composer)