# Symfony in wamp error: Could not open input file: ⌠E:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\symfony÷

Tags: symfony, wamp

I just installed symfony in my wamp according to the tutorials in below websites

http://uniapple.net/blog/?p=298

http://uniapple.net/blog/?p=298

all had finished without any error. But after finished all, when give the command `symfony` in cmd, it shows the below error.

**Could not open input file: ⌠E:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\symfony÷**

and i couldn't figure it out. Please help..

Thank u in advance

Comment: Post the whole error, it looks truncated

Comment: Chances are you are following an old tutorial.  "symfony" command would be in the Symfony root, but I believe it was deprecated for "app/console" commands.  I found a person who had a different problem but found a similar solution here on Stack:  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11126325/how-to-command-run-for-symfony2-in-windows-7)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use the Symfony console, you need to be in CMD and go to your project root:

```
cd C:\Sites\project
```

Before you try any commands, please make sure PHP is in your PATH variable.

Then to do commands in symfony you need to do:

```
php app/console command:action
//for example, do a cache warmup - choose your environment
php app/console cache:warmup --env=[dev|prod]
```

Is this what you mean when you want to use Symfony in cmd?